# MonoDevelop and SQL(Linux) DllNotFoundException libodbc.so

Tags: c#, sql, linux, monodevelop

I am teaching myself C# using MonoDevelop (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) and trying to follow and SQL example, I'm stumbling at the first hurdles.
I keep getting this error at Run Time.

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: libodbc.so

I have read on the web about creating a soft link in /usr/lib to the corresponding file, I have tried this and reinstalled unixODBC, but to no avail.

Has anyone come against this before?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev libmyodbc`

Comment: Thanks, but getting message - Package libmyodbc is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libmyodbc' has no installation candidate

Comment: You can check the following Q&A https://askubuntu.com/questions/800216/installing-ubuntu-16-04-lts-how-to-install-odbc

Comment: Thanks Hackerman, appreciate your input, I have followed the directions and downloaded the connector package and created the files, still got the same problem and am starting to suspect an issue with monodevelop